# firefox 38 hanging with corporate proxy and winbind?

Tags: authentication, firefox, proxy

I seem to have broken firefox 38 and it is unusable.  It just hangs and freezes for long periods of time ranging from a few seconds up to infinity - usually in steps at the authentication prompt for the corporate proxy.  It may have something to do with single-sign-on that has recently been introduced for the proxy to make it easier for people using MS-Windows?

Starting firefox in safe mode from a terminal gives repeated messages:
  "could not obtain winbind domain name!"

I have tried changing my machine from fixed IP to DHCP - it made no difference.
I reset firefox and it runs fine for browsing local files on my hard drive if I don't set the proxy.
I am using Centos 6 with everything up to date.

The strange thing is, I have also tried running firefox from virtual machines inside this same machine - both an old centos 6.0 machine which has not been updated and a Centos 7 machine that was updated a few months ago.  Firefox works perfectly on both of these virtual machines running in virtualbox using NAT for the network.  I get the corporate proxy dialog and can authenticate with no problems.

I have looked through the mozilla help pages and forums.
I have used yum to remove and reinstall firefox.

Any suggestions would be welcome?